# Should I close the socket if setSoTimeout throw an exception?

Tags: java, sockets

Should i close the `socket` in `finally` block after `setSoTimeout` throws an Exception

```
try {
    socket.setSoTimeout(4000);
    //code for reading
} catch(java.lang.Exception ex) {
System.out.println(ex.toString());
} finally {
    socket.close();  <-------is it necessary?
}
```

Comment: Hardly an interesting case. It will only throw an exception if the socket is closed or the value is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the actual exception, but you shouldn't write this method like this. The way you've written it, you will *always* close the socket. The close should be in the catch block, not the finally block.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is necessary.
**Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further networking use (i.e. can't be reconnected or rebound). A new socket needs to be created, 
Closing this socket will also close the socket's InputStream and OutputStream.**

you are probably thinking that when an exception is thrown the socket's resources are freed, but that isn't the case  since `socket.isClosed();` returns false if the exception is thrown, and generally always close the resource in the finally block because you don't really know whether an exception will be thrown or not, and  its a good programming practice.

Comment: Is it really true __Closing this socket will also close the socket's InputStream and OutputStream__

Comment: [yes it is!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close())

Comment: No it isn't necessary. If the exception was thrown because of an illegal timeout value, there is nothing wrong with the socket and it can continue to be used. If it was thrown because the socket was closed, it's already closed. Your second sentence does not follow from your first.